# Trying to make an interactive navigation bar, but can't seem to get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I am working on a website and I can't seem to make it dynamic. My problem is that I can not get the navigation bar to be interactive. When I click it, nothing happens but it refreshes the same page.

(http://puu.sh/8RkDH.png) <- That's what the website looks like with this HTML, javascript and css: http://pastebin.com/Lz1rDwVj.

I thought

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="header"><h1>FILMSTER</h1></div>
    <div id="nav">
                <a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a>
                <a href="#">DIRECTORS</a>
                <a href="#">MOVIES</a>
                <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
                <div class="tabs-container">

<div class="tab" id="HOMEPAGE"></div>
<div class="tab" id="DIRECTORS">asdfasdf</div>
<div class="tab" id="MOVIES">asdfasdf</div>
<div class="tab" id="CONTACT">gfdsgg</div>
```

would make my navigation bar interactive, but when I click one of the categories, It just refreshes the same page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Assign the click handlers:
    var nav = $('#nav'),
        currentTab = nav.find('a').first().text();
    nav.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $(this).text() !== currentTab ) {
            $('.tabs-container').find('.tab').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#' + currentTab).fadeIn();
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Does not seem to help either.

Comment: what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: I want it so when I click the navigation bar, a new tab with a new "page" will open. Right now when I click on the navigation bar, it just refreshes the page.